# How to select date and time from oracle date field using php date function

Tags: php, sql, oracle

How to take the time from date stored as 12/25/2012 5:12:05 AM .

```
date('l F j, Y, g:i a',strtotime($last_login_details[FL_DATETIME]));
```

This above function returned time as 12:00 am which should return 5:12AM.

FL_DATETIME has datatype DATE.

On database, the value is being stored like this :

```
   12/25/2012 5:12:05 AM
```

Comment: It's returning `Tuesday December 25, 2012, 5:12 am` for me using PHP 5.3.19.

Comment: I don't think PHP version matter such things. Just noticed it only returns 25-DEC-12 when I echo $last_login_details[FL_DATETIME]

Comment: **Watch out!**  PHP should be throwing warnings and notices due to invalid syntax that it's automatically correcting for you.  You probably don't have your `error_reporting` level cranked high enough.  Consider going all the way up to -1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the docs - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i1847 -

> For input and output of dates, the standard Oracle date format is DD-MON-YY

That is most likely why `$last_login_details[FL_DATETIME]` is echoing `25-DEC-12`

Try changing your query using `TO_CHAR()`

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(FL_DATETIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS A.M.') AS FL_DATETIME ...
```

see http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html#date format

Comment: So what you mean by that is, even if it's stored in database like dd-mm-yy hm:mm:ss, it only displays date but not the time?

Answer (score 3):

Solved my problem by :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(FL_DATETIME, 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') FROM "FMS_LOG"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in my opinion, you should be storing all dates as unix timestamps. This makes it lot easier for you to do searches against times, and removes any inconsistencies that may arise from date string manipulation.

Second, I tested your code; it looks to be OK from what I can tell. Echo out what you are getting in the $last_login_details[FL_DATETIME] variable. The issue may lie in the variable assignment, and not the date string manipulation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: gives 25-DEC-12 when I echo $last_login_details[FL_DATETIME]

Comment: That's why you're getting the results you're getting. If PHP's date function doesn't actually get a time in there (e.g.: the date is 25-DEC-12), it will automatically default the time to midnight. So 25-DEC-12 becomes Tuesday December 25, 2012, 12:00 am.

Comment: I got it but you can see above, the value is stored like  12/25/2012 5:12:05 AM in DB.

Comment: Which is fine, but that's not what the variable $last_login_details[FL_DATETIME] holds. If you want to make an exact match, you have to store that exact date in the $last_login_details[FL_DATETIME] variable. Otherwise you will never get an exact match.